# Creating a php function with predefined values for a parameter

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following method:

```
public function chooseCar($car)
{
    return 'You chose this car: ' . $car;
}
```

I need to set specific values for what can be passed to chooseCar in the $car argument, for example let the developer choose between 'Mercedes', 'BMW' and 'Ford', is that doable in php?

Comment: Create an array and use `$car` as key or something like that

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php

Comment: Very good question! Please please please don't go with the standard `if else` everyone seems to be suggesting before you read the SplEnum link i pasted above. They are so boring!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below code.

```
public function chooseCar($car)
{   
    $predefined_vals = array( 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford'); 
    if(in_array($car,$predefined_vals)){
       return 'You chose this car: ' . $car;        
    }else{
       return "undefined values chosen"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have one approach for this.

In the function itself, create an array.

And check if the parameter `$car` is [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
public function chooseCar($car = '') {
 $allowedCars = array('Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford');
 if (! in_array($car, $allowedCars)) {
  return FALSE;
 }
 return 'You chose this car: ' . $car;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the parameter is an "acceptable value" like this:

```
var $acceptableCars = [ 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford'];

function chooseCar($car) {
  if (in_array($car, $acceptableCars)) {
    return 'You chose this car: ' . $car;
  }
  throw new Exception('Not a valid car');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this would help you with a fixed list of available cars:

```
<?php

class Cars
{
    private $availableCars = ['Merc', 'Ford'];

    public function chooseCar($car)
    {
        if (in_array($car, $this->availableCars)) {
            return 'You chose this car: ' . $car;
        }

        throw new \Exception('Invalid car chosen!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone suggested, use an enum, this way you're program will be better designed, and you're sure your function is called properly with car, not another thing:

```
class CarBrand extends SplEnum {
  // No value, then undefined
  const __default = 1;
  const MERCEDES = 1;
  const AUDI = 2;
}

function chooseCar(CarBrand $car) {
    if (CarBrand::MERCEDES == $car) {
        echo "Mercedes.\n";
    } elseif (CarBrand::AUDI == $car) {
        echo "Audi.\n";
    }
}

$car = new CarBrand(CarBrand::MERCEDES);
chooseCar($car);
```

Answer (score -1):

By below code if you know types of cars

```
public function chooseCar($car)
{
 switch($car)
 {
  case 'BMW':
    return 'You chose this car: ' . $car;
    break;

  case 'Ford':
    return 'You chose this car: ' . $car;
    break;

  default:
  return 'Soory, Your car not exist in the list';
 }    
}
```

You can also use php in_array() or array_search() functions as describe in other answers.

Comment: why this is maked nagetive?

Comment: What about a default case? For when the $car doesnt exist in the switch.